# Using RequireJS correctly for social plugins

Tags: javascript, beginner, require.js, facebook

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and lately I've been trying things with RequireJS, I'd like to get some feedback on how good/poor my code is and in what ways it can be improved.

My example below is just loading up social plugins - Facebook Like/Share, Twitter Tweet & Google +1. The code is functional and working.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description' content="Your description here." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="your, great, keywords" />
        <title>Your Website Title</title>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567890" />
        <meta property="fb:admins" content="1234567890" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Your Website Title" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.your-website.tld/" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://path/to/your/static/logo.png" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Your description here." />
        <meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
        <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.your-website.tld/">
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="Your Website Title">
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="Your description here.">
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://path/to/your/static/logo.png">
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@your-website">
        <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@your-username">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header-container">
                <header id="header">
                    <div class="social">
                        <div class="twitter">
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Your Name" data-via="YourName" data-related="OtherName" data-hashtags="your-tag">Tweet</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class='fb-like' data-href="https://www.facebook.com/" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui"></div>
                        <div class="plusonec">
                            <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
                            <div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-href="https://www.your-website.tld/"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script data-main="js/app" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**js/app.js:**

```
requirejs.config({
    "shim": {
      "facebook": {
        exports: "FB"
      }
    },
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../app",
      "facebook": "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all",
      "facebookLike": "lib/facebook/like",
      "googlePlus": "//apis.google.com/js/plusone",
      "twitter": "//platform.twitter.com/widgets"
    }
});

requirejs(["facebook"]);
requirejs(["facebookLike"]);
requirejs(["twitter"]);
requirejs(["googlePlus"]);
requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

**lib/facebook/like.js:**

```
define(["facebook"], function(){
  FB.init({
    appId      : "1234567890",
    xfbml      : "true"
  });
});
```

**app/main.js:**

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {

 // Unused placeholder

});
```

Note: I haven't included jQuery in the require config because it isn't actually used here.